# When will Karson finish the mini stable at Lookout Landing?

Tags: zelda-tears-of-the-kingdom

There's an NPC named Karson in Lookout Landing who is working to build a mini stable. Another nearby person says that once the mini stable is finished [I'll be able to register horses there](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gGAiI.jpg).

How long will it take for Karson to finish building the mini stable at Lookout Landing?

[image: Karson talking about building a mini stable]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not so much a *when* factor, but a *how* one.

According to [The Gamer](https://www.thegamer.com/the-legend-of-zelda-tears-of-the-kingdom-stables-guide-all-stable-locations-and-coordinates/) (small spoilers):

> You need to trigger and complete "The Incomplete Stable" by speaking to Lester and Karson in order to finish the Lookout Landing Mini-Stable. The quest, however, is locked until finishing the Rito portion of the "Regional Phenomenon."

Answer (score 1):

The quest is locked behind the Rito portion of "Regional Phenomena". To finish "The Incomplete Stable", all you have to do is fit the plank into the roof of the stable. After completing the quest, you unlock the stable, earn a pony point, and gain access to the quest "Spotting Spot", where you obtain the unique horse Spot.